# How to execute statements only if the preceding statements succeeded

Tags: c++

So I have something like

```
bSuccess = true;

bSuccess = bSuccess && statement1();
bSuccess = bSuccess && statement2();
bSuccess = bSuccess && statement3();
...
```

Is there a better or more idiomatic way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could chain it all together:

```
bSuccess = statement1() && statement2() && statement3();
```

This is "idiomatic", however it isn't completely clear whether this type of code is clear. You are relying on the side-effects of each function call, so at the very least these should be well documented.

Comment: Do you really need to document how `&&` works? You're going to have bigger problems - which you can't solve with documentation - if your developers don't understand `&&`.

Comment: @MSalters I meant documenting the functions and their side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all 3 statements return true if successful, I would use:

```
statement1() && statement2() && statement3();
```

Comment: juanchopanza has a better answer since he assigns the result back to bSuccess.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complex your statements are. Ones that are simple enough, you can just do:

```
bSuccess = statement1() && statement2() && statement3();
```

However, for more complex stuff, I tend to do the following:

```
fOk = 1; // true

if (fOk) {
    LotsOfStuffNotSettingError();
    fOk = SomethingSettingError();
}

if (fOk) {
    LotsMoreStuffNotSettingError();
    fOk = (ThisNeedsToReturnOne() == 1);
}
```

and so on.

That way, the blocks can be *arbitrarily* complex, not limited to simple statements able to be handled with the binary logical operators.

There may be a lot of stuff in each block that doesn't set `fOk` at all but each block should basically end with *one* statement setting `fOk`.

Comment: And, of course, when the blocks DO become arbitrarily complex, you refactor them into 3 new functions, so you still end up with `statement1() && statement2() && statement3()` ;)